# How I get all users except the current_user by username

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my index controller I have this:

```
@users = User.where(User.find_by(username: params[:id]))
```

Comment: What error are you getting? What isn't working? Add more details and explain the issue, otherwise, we cannot help

Comment: `User.where("NOT username = ?", current_user.username)` may work.

Comment: You can do @Clark 's answer more Rubist using .not method like:  `User.where.not(username: current_user.username)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your `current_user` has set in `application_controller.rb` you can create a method there that list all users without him like:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    ...
    def all_users
        User.where.not id: current_user.id
    end
end
```

Whatever, you could use:

```
User.where.not username: current_user.username
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
@curred_user = User.find(params[:username]) 
@users = User.find_by_sql(["SELECT * FROM table WHERE username <> ?",@current_user.username ])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
@users = User.where(username: params[:id]).all - current_user
```